# Scala trait method restricted to implementing type

Tags: scala, types

So I'm having some trouble with what I think is a pretty simple situation in trait implementation, and I'm hoping there is some simple solution that I'm missing. I'd like to have a method on a trait that accepts as a parameter (and returns as a value only the type of the concrete implementation that it is being called on. Specifically:

```
trait Foo {
  type ConcreteFoo // what to put here?
  def combine(that:ConcreteFoo):ConcreteFoo
}

class FooImpl1 extends Foo {
  def combine(that:FooImpl1):FooImpl1 = {
    // implementation
  }
}

class FooImpl2 extends Foo {
  def combine(that:FooImpl2):FooImpl2 = {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

Right now I have a `type Self = FooImpl` on the implementing classes, but I'd rather have something on the trait that takes care of it if possible.

Comment: the solution is called `f-bounded polymorphism`. Read here: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly [F-Bounded Polymorphism:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification)

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[T]]
  def combine(that: T): T
}

class FooImpl1 extends Foo[FooImpl1] {
  def combine(that: FooImpl1): FooImpl1 = {
    ???
  }
}

class FooImpl2 extends Foo[FooImpl2] {
  def combine(that: FooImpl2): FooImpl2 = {
    ???
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I remember though why I didn't take this approach initially. `Foo` actually takes type parameters as well, so when I don't want to be restricted to a concrete `Foo` implementation I don't know how to do that without proliferating type parameters everywhere. ie. `trait Foo[A, F <: Foo[A, F]]; def accumulate(f:Foo[A, _])` fails because `_` doesn't satisfy the bound, but I can't see how to populate it.

Comment: @John You can do `def accumulate(f: F)`, since it's already bound by the trait declaration.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with that snippet. `accumulate` isn't defined on `Foo`, but elsewhere for generic `Foo`s. So actually imagine something like `def accumulate[A](f:Foo[A, _])`. I know I could do `def accumulate[A, F <: Foo[A, F]](f:F)`, but that is exactly the 'proliferation of type parameters that I want to avoid. Is there any why to provide an erased type parameter with the appropriate bounds in this case? Obviously the naive approach gives infinite regress: `def accumulate[A](f:Foo[A, _ <: Foo[A, _ <: Foo[A,_ ...]])`

Comment: Actually it looks like I can use existentials for this: `def accumulate[A](f:Foo[A, F] forSome {type F <: Foo[A, F]})`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a type parameter to your trait like this:

```
trait Foo[A] {
    def combine(that: A): A
}

class FooImpl1 extends Foo[FooImpl1] {
    override def combine(that: FooImpl1): FooImpl1 = ???
}

class FooImpl2 extends Foo[FooImpl2] {
    override def combine(that: FooImpl2): FooImpl2 = ???
}
```